# Generating outline and shadow version of cmr10.mf

Tags: metafont, computer-modern

Does anyone know how you can change the source of `cmr10.mf` so that you can get outline and shadow character.

By outline, I mean something like this:

[image]

and by shadow, I mean something like this:

[image]

For my Persian glyphs, I have some code that works but I can not get it to work with `cmr10.mf`.

You can access the source [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B08sgbJvIcACVUxQT0VBRlM5NWM&usp=sharing). `azinhl.mf` produces outline characters and `zinsh.mf` produces shadow characters. I tried to do the same with `cmr10.mf`; that is at the end of `cmr10.mf`, before `generate roman;`, I put this:

```
bold := 1;
Master := 1;
input azinmacs;
```

and tried to run metafont on the modified `cmr10.mf` but I was not successful in getting outline characters.

Comment: do you need to work from the metafont? getting an outline from metafont has historically been challenging but for the cm fonts at least the work has been done and the outline type1 and ttf versions exist, it's probably easier to generate those kinds of variants from an outline.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yes, I do need to work from the metafont so that both latin and Persian characters are consistent.

Comment: I thought you might say that, sorry I can't help much with metafont:-)

Answer (score 1):

There is a package on CTAN called cmoutlines ( http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cm/cmoutlines ).

The main METAFONT macro to achieve the outline effect is given in the file outlines.mf and should work for other METAFONT fonts as well. The idea behind the macro is very simple: Draw the same glyph several times with tiny shifts and than erase the interior. It is well commented and a shadow version shouldn't be too difficult.